# Vuex state not setting to getter

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I keep trying to get my action to set data so i can pull it from a getter and for some reason it doesnt seem to be working. The data from the getter is always blank. I have the argument payload which matches the case on my switch statement and matches the object in my initialstate. I keep getting a `Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'GOOGLE_DRIVE')` error. What am i doing wrong?

```js
//===============================================================================
// Initial State
//===============================================================================
const initialState = {
  users: {
    GOOGLE_DRIVE: [],
  },
}

const state = { ...initialState }

//===============================================================================
// Actions
//===============================================================================
const actions = {

  //-------------------------------------------------------------------
  // Login user
  //-------------------------------------------------------------------
  async login(state, payload) {
    console.log('login vue')
    try {
      switch (payload) {
        case 'GOOGLE_DRIVE': {
          console.log('payload', payload)
          const GoogleUser = await googleAuth.signIn()
          const user = {
            isSignedIn: GoogleUser.isSignedIn(),
            name: GoogleUser.getBasicProfile().getName(),
            image: GoogleUser.getBasicProfile().getImageUrl(),
            email: GoogleUser.getBasicProfile().getEmail(),
            accessToken: GoogleUser.getAuthResponse().access_token,
            meta: GoogleUser.getAuthResponse(),
            isActive: false
          }
          console.log('user', user)
          //state.users[payload] = user
          //state.commit('users', { GOOGLE_DRIVE: user })
          console.log('user', state)
          break;
        }
        default: 
          throw Error(`invalid drive name, ${payload}`);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(`[login]: `, err);
    }
  },
}

//===============================================================================
// Mutations
//===============================================================================
const mutations = {

  //-------------------------------------------------------------------
  // Reset State
  //-------------------------------------------------------------------
  [RESET_STATE]() {
    Object.keys(initialState).forEach(key => { state[key] = initialState[key] })
  }
}

//===============================================================================
// Getters
//===============================================================================
const getters = {
  users(state, payload, drive) {
    console.log('opayload', payload)
    console.log('drive', drive)
    console.log('get state', state)
    state.users = {  }
  },
}
```

Comment: why have you added the line `state.users = {  }` inside getters?

Comment: Also inside actions it should be `commit('users', { GOOGLE_DRIVE: user })` and not `state.commit('users', { GOOGLE_DRIVE: user })`

Comment: Its blank because its not set yet. you can see im doing console on the getter for data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first argument in an [action](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html#dispatching-actions) is the Vuex context. You've named it `state` and tried to access `state.users` from it, so I believe you're incorrectly assuming it's the Vuex state. Note `users` does not exist in the context, so it would be `undefined`, and `users['GOOGLE_DRIVE']` would then lead to the error you observed:

```js
const actions = {
  async login(state, payload) {
              ^^^^^ ❌ arg1 is context, not state
    ⋮
    state.users[payload] = user  // ❌ state.users is undefined
  }
}
```

However in Vuex 3, actions should not be mutating state directly. That should be moved into a Vuex mutation:

```js
const mutations = {
  'SET_USERS'(state, users) {
    state.users = { ...state.users, ...users }
  }
}
```

Then the action could invoke the mutation through the context's `commit()`:

```js
const actions = {
  async login({ commit }, payload) {
    ⋮
    commit('SET_USERS', { GOOGLE_DRIVE: user })
  }
}
```

Finally, your getter is not declared correctly. The arguments and the state assignment within it make your getter look like a mutation. To fix the getter:

1. Getters receive [`state` as its 1st argument and any other getters as the 2nd argument](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#method-style-access), so remove the other arguments.
2. It needs to return something, typically based on its `state` argument (e.g., the `users` getter should return `state.users`).
3. Getters should not mutate the Vuex state, so remove the `state.users` assignment.

The getter should look like this:

```js
const getters = {
  users: state => state.users,
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vuex-commiting-mutation-from-action?file=src%2Fstore.js)